# How is this average possible?

Tags: trigonometry, average, quantum-mechanics

I am studying atomic physics from *Physics of Atoms and Molecules (B. H. Bransden)* and in some part he says:

\begin{equation}
\left\langle\cos^2 \theta\right\rangle=\dfrac{1}{3}
\end{equation}

But from everything I know this should be equals to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

[Visual proof (page 168 of the book)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAWom.png)

Comment: The formula for the average of $f$ over some interval $[a, b]$ is
$$\frac{1} {b - a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$$
You haven't specified what $a$ and $b$ are, but presumably this equation yields $1/3$.

Comment: It's hard to give advice on so little information. Even your screenshot appears clipped. ... In any case, perhaps this is a question for the [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Blue it is clipped because StackExchange does not let me put it in another way before 10 points of rep. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @RafaJuradoAriza: If you upload a proper screenshot to, say, [imgur](https://imgur.com) and provide a link to it here, then someone can embed the image into your question for you. ... That said, there doesn't appear to be anything special about the screenshot; you could (and should) simply type-in the text, along with other passages from the book that might be helpful (eg, the meaning of $< >$).

Comment: @Blue the book just says "average" but my fail was thinking in 1 dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what $\langle \rangle$ and $\theta$ mean.  If $\theta$ is colatitude on a sphere, where the area element is $\sin(\theta)\; d\theta d\phi/(4\pi)$, then they are right.

Comment: Thanks, then it is the average over the sphere.